# Conditional variance, conditional mean in Stata

Tags: mean, stata

I am using an estimator which assumes that conditional variance is proportional to conditional mean. My model include more than ten variables, where the depended variable and some of the independent variables are continuous, but most of the independent variables are dummies.

Now i would like to check whether this assumption holds. Do you know, how can i do so in **Stata**?